# Use PowerMock to prevent static initialization

Tags: java, junit, mockito, powermock, powermockito

So I have a static variable in my class under test. I have tried to mock it With Powermockito but I am getting error.

```
public class ClassUnderTest{
  private static EntityManager em = AppEntityManager.createEntityManager();
   public static String methodUnderTest(){
       // this method dosent use EntityManager em
   }
}
```

---

My test class is like this:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({ AppEntityManager.class, ClassUnderTest.class })

public class ClassUnderTestTest {
 @Mock
 private EntityManager emMock;
 @InjectMocks
 private ClassUnderTest feMock;

 static ClassUnderTest fe = new ClassUnderTest();

 @Before
 public void setUp() throws Exception {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
 }

 @Test
 public void test() {
     PowerMockito.mockStatic(ClassUnderTest.class);
    PowerMockito.mockStatic(AppEntityManager.class);
    Mockito.when(AppEntityManager.createEntityManager()).thenReturn(emMock);


        String s = ClassUnderTest.methodUnderTest(myParams);
        // assertEquals(prams[i][1], s);
        System.out.println(s);

  }

}
```

### The error is

```
Feb 22, 2018 9:37:31 AM oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver registerMBeans
SEVERE: Error while registering Oracle JDBC Diagnosability MBean.
java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: loader (instance of org/powermock/core/classloader/MockClassLoader) previously initiated loading for a different type with name "javax/management/MBeanServer"
```

Can you tell me where I am going wrong?
I just want to test `methodUnderTest()` and so is there a way I can prevent that static initialization of `EntityManager em`?

Comment: By practicing better design principles. Tightly coupling to that static dependency is now making your code difficult to test.

Comment: Shouldn't you be using the inverted form when mocking that method? Mockito.doReturn(emMock).when(AppEntityManager).createEntityManager();

Comment: Can't change the Base code. Is there a way around?

Comment: what is this `ClassUnderTest.methodUnderTest` ? You are calling methodUnderTest with class Instance, but methodUnderTest is not a static method

Comment: @pvpkiran my bad. Its a static method. edited the question. Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code works for me

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({ AppEntityManager.class}) 
public class ClassUnderTestTest {

  @Mock
  private EntityManager emMock;

  @Before
  public void setUp() throws Exception {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
  }

  @Test
  public void test() {
    PowerMockito.mockStatic(AppEntityManager.class);
    Mockito.when(AppEntityManager.createEntityManager()).thenReturn(emMock);

    String s = ClassUnderTest.methodUnderTest(myParams);
    // assertEquals(prams[i][1], s);
  }

}
```

Some points

1. Since EntityManager is not `@Aurowired`, there is no need for `@InjectMocks`.
2. Since you want the code under `ClassUnderTest::methodUnderTest` to be called, don't use  ClassUnderTest in `@PrepareForTest`
3. Don't do `PowerMockito.mockStatic(ClassUnderTest.class);`

Having said all of these. You should seriously consider refactoring your code to minimize(if possible eliminate) all static methods and fields.

Comment: Thanks for help. Got it working. The thing with this code is that it is almost 8 year old and is working fine so no one wants to refactor it. Recently we were pushed to have unit Tests for our code and that's why these things are being uncovered. That being said, I will make a call to team for refactoring this class. This method is actually private in the class, so now I have to use reflection too but that should be easy if mockito doesn't interfere with refletions .

Answer (score 1):

By practicing better design principles.

> Can you tell me where I am going wrong?

Tightly coupling to that static dependency is now making your code difficult to test.

Make that an explicit dependency that is injected via constructor.

```
public class ClassUnderTest{
    private EntityManager em;

    public ClassUnderTest(EntityManager em) {
        this.em = em;
    }

    public String methodUnderTest(){
       // this method dosent use EntityManager em
   }
}
```

Now when testing you can simply pass a null `EntityManager` since it is not needed in the test.

Comment: I understand that code wasn't written keeping best design principles in mind. This is almost 8 year old code, and it wont be easy to call for refactoring.

Answer (score 0):

Use `PowerMockito.when` instead of `Mockito.when`.

And remove `mockStatic` of `ClassUnderTest`.

So:

```
PowerMockito.mockStatic(AppEntityManager.class);
PowerMockito.when(AppEntityManager.createEntityManager()).thenReturn(emMock);
```

Answer (score 0):

As many other already mentioned, you really shouldn´t use static dependency’s as it leads to that kind of horrible testable design.

However, if you cannot change the code under test, you could inject the EntityManager via reflections:

```
public class ClassUnderTestTest {

    private ClassUnderTest classUnderTest;

    @BeforeEach
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        final Field entityManagerField;

        classUnderTest = new ClassUnderTest();

        //Use getDeclaredField(...) since field is private
        entityManagerField = classUnderTest.getClass()
                                           .getDeclaredField("em");
        //Set accessible since field is private
        entityManagerField.setAccessible(true);
        entityManagerField.set(classUnderTest, 
                               Mockito.mock(EntityManager.class));
    }

    @Test
    public void test() {
        String s = classUnderTest.methodUnderTest();
        // assertEquals(prams[i][1], s);
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}

class ClassUnderTest{
    private static EntityManager em;
    public String methodUnderTest(){
        // this method dosent use EntityManager em
        // but solution don´t care
        return "";
    }
}
```

That way you can also close Pandora´s Box aka PowerMock and continue with basic UnitTesting and mocking.